# Python subprocess call is not working

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a Python program and I need to execute this rather long shell command and receive outputs within my script.

```
test = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("find /home/disk1 -maxdepth 0 -name folder1* -o -name folder7*"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
test.communicate()
```

I've tried all the possible variations of the code, like adding 'executable="/bin/bash" in the arguments, or using subprocess.check_output, etc.

Whenever I run this and check the output by typing 'test.communicate()', I'm getting all the files in '/home/disk1' directory instead of the files that I wanted as per the command. When I type this find search in the shell, it works fine. I don't know why it isn't working. I've spent the last two hours in the internet in vain. I'm baffled here, please help me out.

EDIT: As per the comments, I've also tried omitting 'shell=True' from the arguments, the response in that case is:
`(b'', None)`
I'm expecting name of 4 files with this command. This still isn't right. Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm not looking for files, I'm looking for folders.

Comment: you don't need `shell=True`

Comment: ...not just "don't need", but "shouldn't use", as a general rule. `shell=True` is Considered Harmful, and entirely defeats the purpose of using `shlex.split()`.

Comment: ...by the way, you should use the `-print0` argument to find to NUL-delimit its output, and `.split('\0')` to divide it up -- otherwise, filenames containing newlines (which, yes, are entirely legal) will mess you up.

That's assuming, of course, that you don't do the sane and correct thing and use `os.walk()` instead.

Comment: You don't even need to fork a child to run `find` here. Just use `glob.glob('/home/disk1/file[17]*')` to get a list of matching file names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The command

   ```
   find /home/disk1 -maxdepth 0 -name file1* -o -name file7*
   ```

   will not produce any output. The only object at depth 0 is `/home/disk1` and its name does not match either of the expressions. So the expected result of running that command is empty. You probably wanted `-maxdepth 1`. However, if you don't need a recursive search, `find` is overkill; you can just do a glob expansion on the patterns.
2. When you specify `shell=True` in the constructor for `subprocess.Popen`, you are expected to pass a single string containing the entire command, which will then be passed to a shell. You can do this either by providing a single string argument or a list with one element which is the string. With `shell=False`, you need to provide a list whose first element is the program to run, and whose remaining elements are the arguments. Thus, any of the following will produce the expected result:

   ```
   test = subprocess.Popen(
            "find /home/disk1 -maxdepth 1 -name file1* -o -name file7*"
            , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
   test = subprocess.Popen(
            ["find /home/disk1 -maxdepth 1 -name file1* -o -name file7*"]
            , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
   test = subprocess.Popen(
            shlex.split(
                "find /home/disk1 -maxdepth 1 -name file1* -o -name file7*")
            , stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
   test = subprocess.Popen(["find", "/home/disk1"
                                  , "-maxdepth", "1"
                                  , "-name", "file1*"
                                  , "-o"
                                  , "-name", "file7*"]
                           , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   ```

   I would use the last one, myself.
3. It's not well-documented what `subprocess.Popen` does with a list of more than one element when `shell=True` is specified, and this usage is not recommended. The Posix implementation adds all the elements of the list to ["sh", "-c"], and then executes that. In effect, that will execute the following:

   ```
   sh -c find /home/disk1 -maxdepth 1 -name "file1*" -o -name "file7*"
   ```

   Here, the argument to `-c` is just `find`, `/home/disk1` becomes `$0`, and `$1` through `$7` are set to the remaining arguments. The end result is that `find` is executed with no command-line arguments (in a process whose name is `/home/disk1`). `find` with no arguments produces a recursive listing of all files starting at the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks, `glob` is what I need for my scenario, I was oblivious of its existence. About the `maxdepth`, `maxdepth 0` works perfectly for me on the shell but for some reason it only worked with `maxdepth 1` with subprocess. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rrlamichhane: according to `man find`: "-maxdepth 0 means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments." Perhaps you have an alias for `find` or perhaps you wrote `find /home/disk1/*`. Shrug. It certainly works as documented on my system.